# apppath codeigniter but i got wrong path

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have path like this

```
APPPATH.'libraries/login.php';
```

but, output that i got

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_redis\application\libraries/login.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_redis\index.php on line 303

it should be

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_redis/application/libraries/lib_redis/autoloader.php
```

Comment: You're requesting `libraries/login.php` and you're expecting it to retrieve `lib_redis/autoloader.php`. That's not gonna work.

Comment: I suggest that you read the full CodeIgniter documentation and carefully check through all of your configuration settings.  Did you properly set your directory paths in the `index.php` file?

Comment: it doesn't matter about what I requested.
I want the output like this, focus on tag '\'
C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_redis\application\libraries/login.php
I want the output like this, focus on tag '/'
C:/xampp/htdocs/ci_redis/application/libraries/login.php

Answer (score -1):

first move that folder into your project folder if you're having project named "project" then move that "library" folder into the "project" folder then include
it as : include_once('library/login.php'); 
as far i could understand your issues i would suggest this solution hope it works....